# How to update magento 2 checkout layout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am trying to update my checkout layout to use two columns, so the checkout fields are in the left column and the cart summary is in the right column.

In my checkout_index_index.xml, I have created two containers like:

```
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-main col-md-6">

</container>
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-aside col-md-6">

</container>
```

I am unsure how I can move the elements/items within the onepage.phtml into the correct columns?

Can anyone please advise how it is possible to update the checkout layout?

checkout_index_index.xml

http://cnhv.co/1bq62

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the element inside XML,  you can add `before` or `after` inside `<container>` parameter.

So your codes can modify like this:

```
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-main col-md-6" before="<block_name>">

</container>
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-aside col-md-6" after="<block_name>">

</container>
```

Depends on where you want to place, you can use `before` or `after` respectively. Remember to clear cache after any edits take effect.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv